# Ionic 3 - Handle permissions popup through promises

Tags: android, ionic-framework, promise, ionic3

I'm trying to create an application where it will download and save image to a directory. I've successfully implemented that.

When the app is uninstalled and reinstalled, I'm trying to use the same folder that was created by the app and used earlier. But the problem is, when the file is downloaded first time after the re installation, Android is prompting the user for the permission to store files. Something like in this image,

[image]

But before the user press allow, error block in the downloadImage function executes and shows "Download Failed!" message. Here is the code I'm using,

```
  downloadImage(imageURL) {
    var folderName = 'FolderName';
    this.createDirectory(folderName).then(() => {
      const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();        
      const imageName = imageURL.split('/').pop();

      fileTransfer.download(imageURL, this.storageDirectory + 'FolderName/' + imageName).then((entry) => {
          const alertSuccess = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: `Download Succeeded!`,
              subTitle: `${imageURL} was successfully downloaded to: ${entry.toURL()}`,
              buttons: ['Ok']
          });
          alertSuccess.present();
      }, (error) => {
        const alertFailure = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: `Download Failed!`,
              subTitle: `${imageURL} was not successfully downloaded. Error code: ${error.code}`,
              buttons: ['Ok']
          });
          alertFailure.present();
      });
    });
  }

  createDirectory(folderName): Promise<Boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        return false;
      }

      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        this.storageDirectory = this.file.externalRootDirectory;
      }
      else if(this.platform.is('android')) {
        this.storageDirectory = this.file.externalRootDirectory;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }

      this.file.checkDir(this.storageDirectory, folderName).then((success) => {
        resolve(true);
      })

      this.file.createDir(this.storageDirectory, folderName, false)
      .then((success) => {
        resolve(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(false);
      });
    });
  }
```

Is there a way to defer the further execution until the user clicks 'Allow' through promise or something and try the download only after that?